# Laravel: When creating a record with relations, cannot insert foreign key into table

Tags: forms, laravel, dropdown

I am following this exercise of an "intermediate task list" from Laravel 5.2 documentations and have some difficulty understanding how [this piece of code](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/quickstart-intermediate#creating-the-task) works.

```
$request->user()->tasks()->create([
    'name' => $request->name,
]);
```

#### Question 1

Specifically, I am confused at the relation between the `user()` and `tasks()` methods. Why and how exactly can we make the `user()` and `tasks()` methods available from the `$request` object?

#### Question 2

I created a similar app and has `Person` and `Country` models. I want to pass the `country_id` input from a dropdown list, but I can't get the database updated, using the following code.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'country_id' => 'required|max:3',
    ]);

    $request->user()->people()->create([
        'name' => $request->name,
        'country_id' => $request->country_id,
    ]);

    return redirect('/people');
}
```

Why is it that the country_id cannot be saved to the table? I tried changing the `user()` to `country()` but the error message says, "class Country" was not found. But why is the 'user()' in the tutorial available then? I am baffled.

Comment: The user() method of request is available if the user making the request is authenticated. Since it uses user model it can also fetch the related model, for tasks () to work task relationship must be defined in user model

Comment: Thank you @Digitlimit for your answer. I think i got it now. Regarding the country_id let me see if I can get more clues..

Comment: About country_id you need to understand how eloquent relationship works. Check documentation for eloquent model relationship

Comment: You can also ensure country_id is in $fillable = [ 'country_id'] in People model

Comment: @Digitlimit Thanks! This does the trick. I should have read through the Eloquent doc and Relations before asking. Thank you so much.

Comment: Let me add it as answer :)

Comment: @Digitlimit Please do! It will help a lot of beginners like me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `user()` method of request is available if the user making the request is authenticated.

Since it uses `User` model it can also fetch the related model. For `tasks()` to work `Task` relationship must be defined in user model.

For `country_id` to be created(mass assigned) ensure its included in `$fillable` property of the `People` model

`$fillable = ['country_id']`

Please read Eloquent model relationship section in Laravel documentation.